# <!DOCTYPE html> php

Tags: php, unity3d, сервер, хостинг

Подключал хост для Unity. Все подключил, сделал проверку. Должно было вывести написанную мной строку, но вместо этого выводит

```
<?php


if (!isset($_POST['Login'])) exit;

$_POST['Login']="222" ;

if ($_POST['Login'] == "222")  echo 'Registred';
else {
echo 'Not Register';
}

?>
```

И контроллер откуда я вызывают хостинг

```
 private IEnumerator Send()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Login", login.text);

    WWW www = new WWW("https://pianica.000webhostapp.com", form);
    yield return www;
    if (www.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error " + www.error);
        yield break;
    }
    Debug.Log("working " + www.text);
}
```

Comment: у вас не подключен php в веб-сервере. Поэтому файл он отдаёт "как есть"

Comment: А как его можно подключить?

Comment: свяжитесь с техподдержкой хостинга

Comment: У моего хостинга не работает тех поддержка. Подскажите пожалуйста, я просто совсем новичок в этой теме

Comment: Я связался, сказали что php изначально подключены. Может можно как то еще исправить эту проблему?